# Rails, how to validate an html string using a pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to solve an issue. In my CMS for the content's title I'm using an HTML string: in the title I have the content title and also some link to related contents like galleries and video.
The format of my HTML string is

```
<h2 class="title">
  <a href="/news/.....">Content title</a> | <a href="other link">Pictures</a> | <a href="other link">Videos</a>
</h2>
```

The H2 tag is inside the view, users will edit with an HTML editor the content between H2 tag. The problem is that sometimes with a Wysiwyg editor they place a `<p>` inside and they change the structure. How can I validate the structure in a before save callback?

Basically every title must have a `<a>` tag with a title and a link and several other `<a>` tag separated by a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to parse the HTML. Unlike a regular expressions Nokogiri actually understands HTML and you can use CSS selectors for predicates.

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<h2 class="title"><a href="/news">News</a> | <a href="/pictures">Pictures</a> | <a href="/videos">Videos</a></h2>'

frag = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
h2 = frag.children[0]
links = h2.css('a')

unless h2.text == links.map(&:text).join(' | ')
  puts "the format is wrong"
end
```

I would put this in a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators).